# Angular form validation with UI Utils

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, submit

I am looking to validate a form and disable the submit based on no form errors. I am leveraging UI Utils. The email validation, password matching and password message works, just not the submit.

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-controller="registerFormController">
    <div class="facebookButton">
        <div class="lucida">Sign In With Facebook</div>
    </div>

    <form ng-submit="processForm()" name="registerForm" name="password" class="registerForm">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="registerEmail block" ng-model="formData.email">

        <input type="password" placeholder="password" required class="registerPassword block" ng-model="formData.password">

        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password2" required ui-validate=" '$value==formData.password' " ui-validate-watch=" 'formData.password' "class="registerPassword2 block" ng-model="formData.password2">

        <span ng-show="registerForm.password2.$error.validator">Passwords do not match!</span>


        <button type="submit" class="create-account" ng-disabled="'!registerForm.$error.validator'">Create Account</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

If a CodePen / PLNKR or any additional code is needed, I can definitely provide. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your mark up to this:

```
<button type="submit" class="create-account" ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid">Create Account</button>
```

You also need to remove this from the form tag:

```
name="password"
```

Comment: not sure why "name=password" was there. Worked! Thanks.